# Caching Framework Recommendations

Tags: c#, performance, caching

Its seems that this question has been ask many time before, however none of the questions I have read really reached any general consensus or substantiated conclusion.  So....

I have a .NET 3.5 application framework that is made up of the following nodes:

1. NET.TCP WCF Listener Service (OS Level Service)
2. A request processing framework that sits under the listener
3. An SQL 2008 database that contains configuration data
4. An SQL 2008 database that contains a store of processed requests (i.e. message data in, message data out, times, status logs etc)

The framework works exactly as required and I am getting great/acceptable response times.  However I need to get these response times down as low as they possibly can be.  One of the obvious solutions is to implement caching of the, rarely changing, configuration data (node #3).

The key requirements of the caching model would be:

1. Ability to have cached objects expire after they have not been used for X timespan (i.e. sliding expiration)
2. Ability to have cached objects expire after X timespan regardless of their last use.
3. Ability to clear, either entirely or selectively, the cache in a thread safe manner and therefore not impact on any process that may be querying the cache at the time the clear methods are called

As the framework is not a web app, `System.Web.Caching` cannot be used (well thats the general advice I have read).  It seems a little overkill to add the MS Enterprise Framework to the project just for Caching Application Block functionality (that and I have heard that MS are deprecating this as .NET 4 now has `System.Runtime.Caching`).  It isn't viable to use .NET 4 and therefore `System.Runtime.Caching`

Then there is another aspect to consider.  The configuration data is coming out of an SQL database and this will perform its own caching of commonly used data.  So maybe caching isnt required here at all?  That said the DB and the Service reside on seperate servers, therefore caching in memory on the server will remove the overhead of the network comms between server and DB.

So the question is what caching model, if any, would you suggest for this?  At the moment I am leaning towards writing my own, however if this can be avoided I am all ears.

**EDIT**

After looking at the MS Enterprise Library a little more it seems that this may be a viable solution.  It meets most of the requirements and is not overly complicated.  This afternoon I intend to do some threading tests to make sure that it works as expected.  The question that I do have though is:  Is this library production ready or is it more a technology demonstration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a single server, then I would go with MS Enterprise Library Caching Block. It works fine in a prod environment. If you get into multiple servers, then I would move to something like memcached.

Comment: There are multiple servers so I did consider Memcache - however if I had single memcache server there will be network traffic to get/set cache items so I may as well rely on caching in SQL itself.  More than happy to be proved wrong on this one.

Comment: @MrEyes - you are probably correct there. I was thinking more along the lines of caching something more computationally intensive than a static data set, and something that 1 server might want to update that other servers would immediately need to know about. Since it sounds like you would be caching basically static data, keeping it in-memory on each server sounds like a fine idea. I've even used Oracle's continuous notification feature to notify my application if a table changes, so the app would know to automatically reload some data (if you happen to use Oracle).

Comment: I would say that for the type of data it sounds like the OP is wanting to cache that the EL Caching Block is suitable, even for multiple servers.  It's OK if two server instances each cache the same data.  And yes, if the cache is expanded to include expensive resources (e.g. high computation or retrieval cost) then it may be worth looking at a solution like memcached to cache those results for all servers instead.  But for what you originally asked about, you can feel save just using the EL Caching Block on each server.